# server-side file upload not saving my file

Tags: asp.net, http-post

on the server side, I've got these:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
</form>
```

CS:

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];
   if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
   {
      string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Files/", fname)));
   }
}
```

Client Side app: it uses WebClient but I didn't think this was needed for any solution since webclient is pretty simple and straight forward. Anyways, here's the code

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            

            Uri uploadAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/WebUpload/default.aspx");

                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_UploadProgressChanged);
                wc.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadFileCompleted);
                wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                wc.UploadFile(uploadAddress, "POST", m_filename);

        }

        void wc_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                txtProgress.Content = e.Error.Message;
            else
                txtProgress.Content = "Completed";
        }

        void wc_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtProgress.Content = String.Format("{0}% completed",
                e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
```

as for the client app: it's a simple webclient using uploadfileasync via HTTP POST to the aspx page.

Question: files gets saved normally using the aspx page but for the client app, the file gets uploaded and but doesn't get saved on the folder. What might be happening? I'm pretty sure this is a server side problem.

Update: added the client side code. The client app works on another (but asp classic) server so I'm doubting that the client is the one that needs fixing.

Comment: Sorry please explain, by Client app do you mean a seperate program ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with the file on the client side? Your code uploads the file to the server and stores it there in the Files folder.

Comment: @jan exactly. pretty straightforward. post the file stream. server gets it and is (or should be) saved on the "Files" folder. This worked on a different server app that runs on ASP classic. The problem is that the file gets uploaded but is never created/saved on the folder

Comment: That won't work. Your server code saves the file in the btnUploadClick handler which isn't called when simply posting the file to the page. You have to either save the file in `Page_Load()` event or post the matching __EVENTTARGET __EVENTARGUMENT values to the page.

Comment: I'll go make those changes. In any case could you add more and post that as an answer since it would look awkward to answer my own question :P

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. 

The file receiving code should have been in the page_load, that was careless of me. Another problem was the string name of the index of the file (Request.Files["myFile"]) which should be of the same id as the input control in the aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting my comment since Jan never posted an answer.

Thanks to Jan for pointing me to the right direction. The file receiving code should have been in the page_load, that was careless of me. Another problem was the string name of the index of the file (Request.Files["myFile"]) which should be of the same id as the input control in the aspx page.